# Formulation of a phrase with the word “match”

Tags: grammar, translation

I am novice to English language. Is it possible to write: "there are several dimensions that match.."?

Comment: Sure it's possible – you just did so. Now, will it sound okay buried inside a longer sentence? We can't help you with that unless we get more of an idea of how you'd use this sentence. (Some hints on how to improve this question can be found at [this meta post](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please).)

Answer (score 1):

That sentence is grammatically valid. I don't know what you're trying to say so I can't say if it expresses the idea. Dimensions match in what way? It might be clear in context.